How can I apply the GARCH-MIDAS model to the FTSE MIB using the CPU as an explanatory variable?
I am trying to understand how climate risk impacts the financial market and I am calculating VaR and ES. I am applying the GARCH-MIDAS model to the FTSE MIB, using the Climate Policy Uncertainty Index (CPU) by Konstantinos Gavriilidis as an explanatory variable.
The problem is that within my model confidence set, the best results are given by the GARCH and GJR models, while the GARCH-MIDAS is always the worst. Is this possible?
P.S. I am using functions provided by my professor to calculate the GARCH-MIDAS.

What is impossible is that GARCH-MIDAS would never be the worst model. The opposite is therefore a given, and so your case is possible. We would need more details to evaluate how plausible that is, though.

FTSEMIB presents daily returns and CPU is monthly. To calculate the VaR and ES in the GARCH MIDAS, I use this function:
fit_gm_nA <- ugmfit(  model = "GM", skew = "NO", distribution = "norm", daily_ret = rendimenti_FTSEMIB_day,  mv_m = cpu_mv, K = K, R = 1000, out_of_sample = 639)
To calculate the VaR and ES out of sample, the code is as follows:
VaR_gm_n_oos<-qnorm(0.05)fit_gm_nA$est_vol_oos
ES_gm_n_oos<- -fit_gm_nA$est_vol_oosdnorm(qnorm(0.05))/0.05

While to calculate the VaR and ES in GARCH and also in GJR, I use:
pred_garch_11oos <- ugarchforecast(
fitORspec = fit_garch_11is, data = rendimenti_FTSEMIB_day, n.ahead = 1, n.roll = (TT_oos - 1))
Conditional variance
pred_garch_11_cond_var <- pred_garch_11oos@forecast$sigmaFor
u_garch_11 <- residuals(fit_garch_11is)
h_garch_11 <- sigma(fit_garch_11is)
z_garch_11 <- u_garch_11 / h_garch_11
5% quantile of standardized residuals
z05_garch_11 <- quantile(z_garch_11, 0.05)
z05_garch_11

Conditional mean of standardized residuals below the 5% quantile
c05_garch_11 <- mean(z_garch_11[z_garch_11 < z05_garch_11])
c05_garch_11
VaR
Multiply the standardized quantile by the conditional var
VaR_garch_oos_n <- z05_garch_11 * pred_garch_11_cond_var
ES
Multiply the standardized conditional mean by the conditional var
ES_garch_oos_n <- c05_garch_11 * pred_garch_11_cond_var

Instead of posting several long comments, please include additional information by editing the post. Thank you.

A sequel to this has been posted here.

I would to fix a little stuff in this command: fit_gm_nA <- ugmfit( model = "GM", skew = "NO", distribution = "norm", daily_ret = rendimenti_FTSEMIB_day, mv_m = cpu_mv, K = K, R = 1000, out_of_sample = 639)

I think that FTSEMIB index have fat tails (but without the values of skewness and kurtosis I don't say that surely) because this is a stylezed fact in financial time series (in particular when we have financial returns). In this case the argument "skew" in your piece of code might be "YES";
The distribution of your innovation ("distribution") might be "std" for the previous reason. I think that the "shape" parameter that you find in summary statistics of your model might be statistical significant;
R=1000 is too low. For a more robustness of your model, this argument could be at least 5000. This rise the computation, but could make your model better than the univariate GJR-GARCH model without MIDAS variable when you compute VaR and ES, I think.

